# Equivalent criterion for algebraic independence over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

How do we show that two distinct complex numbers which are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ are also algebraically independent over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation: what does $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ mean?

Comment: @KevinLong In this context it is fairly certain that $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{Q}$ inside $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah, thanks, I'm being rather forgetful.

Comment: Showing this is part of the proof that the [transcendence degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) of a field extension is well-defined. That should give you somewhere to look for the answer in your favorite abstract algebra textbook.