# Algebraic independence over subfields and algebraic closure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Are my following conjectures formulated linguistically and mathematically correct?

1.) $K$ be a field, $O$ a superfield of $K$, and $v_1,...,v_n$ be algebraically dependent over $K$. $v_1,...,v_2$ are algebraically dependent over $O$ then.

2.) $K$ be a field, $U$ a subfield of $K$, and $v_1,...,v_n$ be algebraically independent over $K$. $v_1,...,v_2$ are algebraically independent over $U$ then.

3.) $K$ be a field, $\overline{K}$ the algebraic closure of $K$, and $v_1,...,v_n$ be algebraically independent over $K$. $v_1,...,v_n$ are algebraically independent over $\overline{K}$ then.

Are these conjectures true?

Is this obvious and need not be proven?

Do you have some literature references?

Comment: You did not mention where $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ existed. Is it just any $O$- (resp. $K$-, $\overline{K}$-) algebra?

Comment: @ Mindlack I want to consider the most general cases. Is indicating where $v_1,...,v_n$ exist necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Alg. dependence over $K$ implies alg. dependence over a field extension of $K$. Yes, indeed. If an equation holds over $K$, it holds over the field extension.

Question 2: This is the contraposition of question 1: Alg. independence of a field extension of $K$ implies alg. independence over $K$.

Question 3: Your link points in the right direction.

Comment: I found hints for the proof of conjecture 3 here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926799/equivalent-criterion-for-algebraic-independence-over-mathbbq The proof can go with the invariance of the transcendence degree to algebraic field extensions.